# It is possible to use eval to test an equality?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I try to get a boolean return from a simple condition. it is possible to use Eval function to do that or may I have to use a if statement ?

here is my expression :

```
alert(eval($("#val1").val() + $("#val2").val() == $("#result1").val()));
```

It's numeric values like 1 + 1 = 2 // true

Comment: `eval()` takes a string parameter, see https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval - so the answer to your question is "yes", but you're using it wrong. Maybe you should elaborate what you're trying to do, it's always better to **avoid** `eval()` if possible.

Comment: Maybe it is, however your code seems like it has some problems, can you provide us with the values of your variables maybe so we can work from there?

Comment: if your values are numbers and you want to add numbers and compare that to result,you should pars values

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should convert them to numbers like this:

```
alert(Number($("#val1").val()) + Number($("#val2").val()) ==  Number($("#result1").val()));
```

if you don't convert them to numbers,java-script assumes they are strings and does a concatenation, and then `val1(1) + val2(1) = 11`

```js
$("#btn").click(function(){
     console.log("Converted To Numbers: " + $("#val1").val() + " + " + $("#val2").val() + " = " + (Number($("#val1").val()) + Number($("#val2").val())));
    alert(Number($("#val1").val()) + Number($("#val2").val()) ==  Number($("#result1").val()) );
});

$("#btn2").click(function(){
    console.log("No Conversion: " + $("#val1").val() + " + " + $("#val2").val() + " = " + $("#val1").val() + $("#val2").val());
    alert($("#val1").val() + $("#val2").val() == $("#result1").val() );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="val1">
<input type="text" id="val2">
<input type="text" id="result1">
<br>
<input type="button" id="btn" value="Convert To Numbers">
<input type="button" id="btn2" value="No Conversion">
```